# Usage of "doesn't" in future sentence?

Tags: negation, subjunctives, do-support, sarcasm

My friend is going to board into the train.
To give a sarcastic sent off… shall I say,

> "Make sure your train doesn't derail"

Is "doesn't" appropriate here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of an error in Modern English that is now accepted.  Prior to this, in the sentence above, the present subjunctive would have been used.  A very correct form would be:

> Make sure [that] your train **not derail**.

Many native English speakers who hate the sound of the present subjunctive, but also don't like the present tense sound in this instance, will use a modal herein "to try to preserve some semblance of" the subjunctive:

> Make sure [that] your train **should** not derail.
>
> Make sure [that] your train **shall** not derail.
>
> Make sure [that] your train **will** not derail.
>
> Make sure [that] your train **might / may** not derail.

The reason it should be the present subjunctive above is because "make sure" means "see to it".

> "See to it that your train **not derail**."

In English, "see to it" is usually followed by a subjunctive.  When "make sure" means "check to see whether" or "check whether", then there is no present subjunctive used.  For instance:

> Make sure that John **has** his homework done. (This means "check to
>   see whether John **has done** his homework.")
>
> Make sure that John **have** his homework done. (This means "see to it
>   that John **have done** his homework (*by the time I get home*).")

Here are some good examples that I've listed in the comment section, but that I want to add to my answer to show this concept better:

> "I will see to it that he **be** hanged for his crimes!"
>
> "I'll see him **[be]** hanged for his crimes!"
>
> "I'll make sure that he **be** hanged for his crimes!"
>
> "It is important that he **be** hanged for his crimes, so let him
>   **be** hanged!"
>
> "So **be** it!" (i.e. "So **be** he hanged" or "So **shall** he **be**
>   hanged")

Now, what I am telling you is technically-correct English; however, very few native speakers of English follow the rule I've state above.  It is the rule, however, because I've researched it as I, too, have asked the same question.  The present subjunctive in Modern English doesn't get much éclat, so that's the reason that "doesn't" is often used in this situation.

Comment: How about "Make sure your train *wouldn't* derail"? Is it ok as a present subjunctive clause?

Comment: That would be fine if you said it in the past or in a conditional sense.  "When you were young, you would make sure your train wouldn't derail" or "If I were you, I would make sure that your train wouldn't derail." However, in your sense, I don't think "wouldn't" would work; "shouldn't" would, however, work; so would "will" and "shall" and "may" and "might".

Comment: To me, "Don't make your train derail," sounds better than "Make sure that your train should not derail" .

Comment: I agree there are other ways to say it, but you're trying to get around the subjunctive. Notice the bare infinitive **derail** in "Don't make your train **derail**." Reworded and converted, "Make it so that your train **derail**." The conjunction "so that" means "in order that", which is another subjunctive indicator. "I'll make him **go**" is the equivalent of "I'll make it so that he **go**."

Comment: Here's a really good example: "I will see to it that he **be** hanged for his crimes!" "I'll see him **[be]** hanged for his crimes!" "I'll make sure that he **be** hanged for his crimes!" "It is important that he **be** hanged for his crimes, so let him **be** hanged!"

Comment: I think there is an ellipsis of *should* in those clauses. Like, "I will see to it that you *should* be hanged for your crimes!"

Comment: There's no ellipsis. The modal "should" in Modern English is used to replace the present subjunctive by many speakers. Example, "if truth **be** told, I am not very good at this" versus "if truth should be told, I am not very good at this." "If that be the case, I shall eat my hat" versus "if that should be the case" versus "should that be the case". Most native speakers now say "if that's the case". In your case, it's probably more of a case that "shall" should be used to replace the subjunctive: "I will see to it that you *shall* be hanged for your crimes!"

Comment: Oh, I see. I wasn't aware that there is a *will* in that sentence.